# what is the best responsive method for HTML template

Tags: html, responsive-design

mostly we use bootstrap for responsive but there have many peoples need responsive without bootstrap framework. I know about LESS. is that any other way to do my web site responsive perfectly

Comment: the best method depends of what you need. sometimes it's some framework, sometimes you have to write it from scratch. it's all about researching and learning stuff, a lot of testing, a lot of kicking own head against the wall. what's good for me maybe is not good for you and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are plain CSS, and are what most responsive frameworks are built upon.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries